# Stereoisomers of metaldehyde and paraldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

[image]

(1) In case of paraldehyde I see 3 similar chiral carbons. So I divided it into 2 subcases

-two methyls above the plane and one below the plane

-all three above the plane
so, that makes it 2. When I looked this up on Wikipedia I found this,
[image]

can,(1) and (4) not be obtained by simply ring flipping, doesn't that make them *conformers*? **Do I need to count them separately in my count of stereoisomers?**

[image]

this according to me should have 4 stereosiomer(not including conformers) can someone **confirm this answer?** Are there any more im missing out?
[image]

Comment: Looking good! Shows you what Wikipedia is worth. Conformers of paraldehyde do not count as stereoisomers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis for metaldehyde is correct. There are four achiral stereoisomers. The example cited [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134766/number-of-stereoisomers-of-cchclch34) is a bit different. To understand the use of R, S, r and s, see this discussion on the [inositols](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/inositol.html).

[image]

Comment: Shreya, you might be interested in this: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/metaldehyde.html